# MYSQL Function IF Syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to write one function with IF and I am getting Error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 8 Code 1064

This is the function.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `my_fun` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `my_fun` (nid INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN
DECLARE abc varchar(100);
SELECT foo INTO abc FROM my_table WHERE bar = nid;
IF abc = ''
THEN
SELECT foo INTO abc FROM my_table WHERE bar = -1;
RETURN abc;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Am not sure whats the [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) here , I tried `IF abc IS NULL` also.
I just want to check if first select statement returned empty value then execute another statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `END IF` statement.

Your code should be:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `my_fun` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `my_fun` (nid INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN
DECLARE abc varchar(100);
SELECT foo INTO abc FROM my_table WHERE bar = nid;
IF abc = ''
THEN
SELECT foo INTO abc FROM my_table WHERE bar = -1;
END IF;
RETURN abc;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are missing the END IF statement and second why not do the following in the IF condition_statement:

`IF (SELECT foo FORM my_table WHERE bar = nid) IS NULL`
`THEN`
`SELECT foo INTO abc FROM my_table WHERE bar = -1;`
`END IF`

Comment: Using your statement OP will not get the result of first `SELECT` in his variable abc.

Comment: my point exactly, he is only checking the variable to be empty or not using the first SELECT statement, which can be done with my way alternatively.

Comment: With his first select he's selecting some value from my_table into variable abc. If this value is NOT NULL then no further change occur and this value is RETURNed from function. Your code in the same situation will return initial abc value (I suppose, empty string).